# C++ code performance drop in iOS device

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, windows, performance

I have implemented some C++ code, and have run it on a Windows machine. The execution time takes around 220 milliseconds. I ran the same code on an iOS device (iPad), where it takes 1 second for the execution time.

What would be the reason? How can I achieve the same performance on an iOS device? Is there any way to increase the performance of C++ code on such a device?

What are the ways to increase the performance of a C++ code in iOS?

Comment: ... your windows machine is more powerful, what do you expect?

Comment: More powerful, but more disappointing as well ;) I wouldn't associate his windows with power, but maybe his hardware. Just sayin' @Kevin

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the average Windows machine will be a lot more powerful than an iPad for many tasks.

That said, use Instruments (part of Xcode) to profile the code and see where it's spending most of its time, maybe some optimisations for iPad will become clear.